# Creating Dynamic array as part of struct vs dynamic int array

Tags: arrays, c, dynamic, realloc

I am working with dynamic arrays, consider two scenarios -
Scenario 1:

```
typedef struct 
{
int *array;
int dataPtr;
} A;
static A dynaArray;
//Call the function as
dynaAdd(&dynaArray, <pointer to data block>, <length> );

static bool dynaAdd(A *data, int *dataCopy, int len)
{
    int newlen = (data->dataPtr + len); 
    data->array  = (int *) realloc(data->array, newlen * sizeof(int));
    if (!data->array)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    memcpy(&data->array[data->dataPtr], dataCopy,  len* sizeof(int));

   data->dataPtr += len; // update data ptr

 
    return TRUE;
}
```

I create a `static struct A data` (say) and pass to a function as pointer which reallocates length for `A->array` everytime and adds data to it, maintaining a `dataPtr` for index. This works perfectly fine where I can create an A->array of say length 100, use the data and free the pointer and null.

On the other scenario 2 -

```
static int *dynArray;
//Call the function as
dynaAdd(dynaArray, <pointer to data block>, <len>, <dataIdx> );
    
static bool dynaAdd(int *data, int *dataCopy, int len, int dataIdx)
{
    int newlen = (dataIdx + len); 
    data  = (int *) realloc(data, newlen * sizeof(int));
    if (!data)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    memcpy(&data[dataIdx], dataCopy,  len* sizeof(int));

   dataIdx += len ;

 
    return TRUE;
}
```

I just use `int *array` instead of struct, maintaining a `static int dataPtr`(say) to keep track of the next index, pass the array pointer to the function and dynamically grow the array and add contents to it. However, the program crashes after creating some x length array (which keeps varying).
Can someone help understand the difference between the two approaches ? In both scenarios, the goal is to create a dynamic array and keep adding contents to it until the certain data index and then free the array.
Thank you.

Comment: In order to know what you might be doing wrong, we need to see your code.

Comment: Edited the question to add more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second example, you're modifying `data` which is local to the function.  Such a change is not reflected in the calling function, so `dynArray` doesn't change.  And since you reallocated memory, if the memory moved then this pointer is now invalid and attempting to dereference it triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to change the function to accept the address of a `int *`, i.e. an `int **`, for the first argument and make the corresponding changes.  You'll also want to make `dataIdx` a `int *` so changes to that are also propagated back

So your function would now look like this:

```
static bool dynaAdd(int **data, int *dataCopy, int len, int *dataIdx)
{
    int newlen = (*dataIdx + len); 
    *data  = realloc(*data, newlen * sizeof(int));
    if (!*data)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    memcpy(&(*data)[*dataIdx], dataCopy,  len* sizeof(int));

    *dataIdx += len ;

 
    return TRUE;
}
```